# Select AZs that have Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

We have CloudFromation Templates that we deploy to 3 regions and we use !GetAZs intrinsic function as follows:

```html
  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetCIDR2'
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - '1'
        - !GetAZs ''
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private-Subnet-2
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

We set up 2 subnets first sets the index to 0 and the second one sets it to 1. We are doing this because Workspaces are available in specific Availablity Zones. And so far the 3 regions we are deploying have Workspaces available in availability zones at Index 0 and 1.

But now we want to add another availability zone for which the Workspaces are available at 1 and 2 index.

I have a PoC which would use `!Equals` in conditions for that specific region but then it will set up an additional subnet, routing table, etc a whole networking setup just for this availability zone. Which is not ideal. BTW My `!Equals` condition is as follows:

```html
    WorkspaceSubnet: !Equals
    - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
    - 'us-east-1'
```

What I want is something where I could set index on the basis of `!Equals` Condition being ture/false something like as follows:

```html
  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetCIDR1'
      AvailabilityZone: !if
        - WorkspaceSubnet
        - !Select 
          - '2'
          - !GetAZs ''
        - !Select 
          - '0'
          - !GetAZs ''
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private-Subnet-1
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

But this gives me error: `[cfn-lint] E3002: Property Resources/PrivateSubnet1/Properties/AvailabilityZone has an illegal function Fn::if`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we make silly mistakes that are uncaught with the naked eye, when you post it on StackOverflow some of your peers start reviewing, and some care enough to Dig Deep.

Thank [Mehdi Azhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8466043/mehdi) my Mentee for pointing out that it was just a lower-case issue. The intrinsic function `!if` starts with a capital `!If`.

So the correct piece of code would be:

```html
  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref 'PrivateSubnetCIDR1'
      AvailabilityZone: !If
        - WorkspaceSubnet
        - !Select 
          - '2'
          - !GetAZs ''
        - !Select 
          - '0'
          - !GetAZs ''
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private-Subnet-1
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```